# Python 3.5 issue with smtp sending mail

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, smtp

I'm performing simple actions to send some emails with Django

```
connection = get_connection()
connection.open()
```

....

```
connection.close()
```

but when i reach string with `connection.open()` everything just stops, no exceptions or other info. So I went deeper and through smtplib came to socket...

### [pdb cast of issue](http://asciinema.org/a/0i83b753ko6nxiig0qtksq9m7)

And 1 important thing, this bug i get using python 3.5.1, but if i switch to python 3.4.3, all goes just fine.
Have any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The issue appears to be that you are creating a connection within one thread and attempting to use it with another. It appears it should be failing if it is attempting to do the same thing within 3.4 since the code is present within both branches ([3.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L1146)) ([3.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/3.5/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L1147)). The only thing I can think of is that 3.4 isn't creating a different thread and so the issue doesn't occur.

Comment: if set [timeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) i get error:

`File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out`
that means connection to mail server can't be established before time's out, so i think threads are not involved. But why in python 3.4 all ok?(

Comment: Strange, i built python 3.4 on my web server and it looks like i get the same issue and i think it's related to ubuntu 16.04.
Previously i tested on my laptop, it have ubuntu 14.04 - works fine.
So i'm totally confused

Comment: Finally i investigated the issue. Problem was with Scaleway, by default it blocks smtp, but itls very strange cause i reproduced it with my own pc, which have smtp available...